# error bar error centred over cluster

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar, errorbar

I am using ggplot to plot a grouped bar plot of means from a set of weight data across 4 weeks from different groups. I am trying to plot error bars of standard error but they are not centred over each bar, instead they are centred over each cluster. [See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5E8Go.jpg)

I have the script:

```
data <- read.table(file="groups.txt",head=TRUE,sep="\t")
attach(data)
melted <- melt(data, id.vars=c("id", "group"))
means <- ddply(melted, c("group", "variable"), summarise,
           mean=mean(value))
means.sem <- ddply(melted, c("group", "variable"), summarise,
               mean=mean(value), sem=sd(value)/sqrt(length(value)))
means.sem <- transform(means.sem, lower=mean-sem, upper=mean+sem)

m.bp<-ggplot(means, aes(variable, mean)) +   
  geom_bar(aes(fill = group), position = "dodge", stat="identity") + xlab("Age") + ylab("Weight(g)") + scale_x_discrete(labels=c("w1" = "P7", "w2" =  "P14",
                          "w3" = "P21", "w4" = "P28")) + scale_fill_manual(values = c("orange", "chocolate2", "grey32", "grey25"),name="Genotype\n/Sex", breaks=c("kf", "km", "wf", "wm"),
                     labels=c("Dlk1 KO Female", "Dlk1 KO Male", "WT Female", "WT Male"))

m.bp + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=upper,ymin=lower), width=.2, position=position_dodge(0.9),
                          data=means.sem)
```

Which works very nicely to cluster the weight data by group on the basis of age. However, when I plot it my error bars are centred over the cluster rather than individually over each bar. Does any body know how to get the error bars to sit in the correct place?

Comment: `geom_errorbar` doesn't have anything to dodge on as it isn't associated with any group aesthetic.  You could set `fill = group` globally in `ggplot` instead of locally in `geom_bar` or use `group = group` within `geom_errorbar`.

Comment: I did group=group within geom_bar and it worked perfectly! Thank you so so much @aosmith !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placement of error bars in barplot using ggplot2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079064/placement-of-error-bars-in-barplot-using-ggplot2)